# How to configure Google Chrome to delete all cache and local storage of the websites when closing their tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, tabs, browser-cache, local-storage

I am looking for a way to delete all cache and local storage of the websites when closing their tabs on Google Chrome.

In Firefox there is an extension called: "[Self-Destructing Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies/)" that does this job automatically. However in Google Chrome, the closest alternatives are "[Vanilla Cookie Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vanilla-cookie-manager/gieohaicffldbmiilohhggbidhephnjj)" and "[Tab Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-cookies/iahecghojagkcoehfhfknajofkokndjm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)" which both do not delete the local storage when closing the tabs.

For Reference: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78093

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings in Google Chrome and scroll down.

Click Advanced options and click Internet settings.

Select History tab and enable Delete History on exit.

(not confirmed on Windows 10).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My question is different though; I am asking about cache and local storage not history. Besides that, i am not talking about cleaning those stuff on exit but rather on tab level.

Answer (score 0):

Incognito mode? (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + N) Seems to be applicable in this situation.

Comment: The incognito mode deletes history and tracking rather than cookies and local storage. It is completely different than the topic i am talking about.

Comment: @Ken Incognito wipes everything. See the google chrome section on https://blog.whatwg.org/tag/localstorage

Comment: I can't make the incognito mode as my default browsing mode due to its predefined settings. I did an intensive research about this question and it seems there are no extensions at this point in time that behaves like "Self-Destructing Cookies". You either should use the incognito mode or you need to clear things up manually from time to time. Both methods have some obvious disadvantages which explain why in Firefox the "Self-Destructing Cookies" extension have over 100,000 active users although there is also an incognito mode. On any rate, thank you very much for your reply.